# AJUDA COM CODIGO EM C, STRINGS

Tags: c, string

// que mudanças eu tenho que fazer pra fazer cada caractere se repetir uma vez a mais que o anterior?

exemplo:
entrada:
Roberto
saída:
Roobbbeeeerrrrrttttttooooooooo

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main (){
char string[50];
int num, leng;

```
printf("String inicial: ");
scanf("%s,", string);
printf("Numero: ");
scanf("%d", &num);

leng = strlen(string);
char  stringFinal[leng*num];

printf("String final: ");
for (int i = 0; i < leng; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++){
        printf("%c ", string[i]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

}

GRATO

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a definição de string em C, uma possível solução é:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main (){
    char string[50];
    printf("String inicial: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("String final: ");
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<i+1; j++) {
            printf("%c", string[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```